# Bootstrap 3 Collapse in Portlet with tabs not appearing

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portlet with 2 tabs. When I add a collapse command, the collapse icon is there, but the tabs are on top of it so it can't be accessed.

How do I make the collapse appear beside the tabs so the portlet can collapse?

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="portlet box grey tabbable">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>Contact
            </div>
            <div class="tools">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="tabbable portlet-tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab">Secondary</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#portlet_tab1" data-toggle="tab">Primary</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <!-- TAB 1 -->
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="portlet_tab1">
```

Comment: Yeah, I see them. What's your question? Also, Is there a Bootstrap Area 51? If not, I assume you mean Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

All that's needed here is to move the tab container to the left so that the collapse button is viewable and clickable.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-right:30px">
```